# Extract certain number of rows in dataframe based on condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
Group Pos Score
A     V   82
A     V   72
A     W   95
A     W   92
A     W   65
A     W   61
A     X   82
A     X   80
A     X   70
B     V   88
B     V   77
B     W   95
B     W   91
B     W   85
B     W   71
B     X   88
B     X   83
B     X   78
...
#this data frame has groups with values C, D, E, etc also
```

Let's say I want to keep the top number of scores for each `Group`, and each `Pos`. For example, let's say I want to keep the top 1 `Score` for `Pos=V`, top 3 `Score`s for `Pos=W`, and top 2 `Score`s of `Pos=X`

So I want the dataframe to look like

```
Group Pos Score
A     V   82
A     W   95
A     W   92
A     W   65
A     X   82
A     X   80
B     V   88
B     W   95
B     W   91
B     W   85
B     X   88
B     X   83
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
v1 <- unique(df1$Pos)
Map(function(x,y)
   filter(df1, Pos==x) %>%
       group_by(Group) %>% 
       top_n(y, wt = Score), v1, c(1, 3, 2)) %>% 
   bind_rows()
```

Comment: this worked for the most part. One problem is in the case where 2 scores were tied. For example, if I modify the dataframe in my question such that there are 2 entries of `A     V   82`, your code will return 2 rows of `A     V   82`, instead of just 1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also, after I run your code, how can I get the average score for each `Group` and `Pos`. For example,for ` A     X   82` and `A     X   80`, how can I return `A     X   81`, since 81 is the average of 82 and 80?

Comment: @user5739619  For gettting the average score `%>% group_by(Group, Pos) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Score))`  The first part is not clear enough to me.

Comment: where do I enter that code? In between the code in your answer? Or in a new line after the block code in your answer?

Comment: @user5739619  It is after the `bind_rows() %>% group_by(Group, Pos)..`